# python urllib2 urlopen failed to open https link

Tags: python, https, urllib2

I am writing a oauth script using python.
When i try to open the https link "https://www.douban.com/service/auth2/token"

it gives me the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/users/zhangxuan06/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/users/zhangxuan06/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/users/zhangxuan06/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/users/zhangxuan06/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/users/zhangxuan06/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/home/users/zhangxuan06/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

But when I open this link with browser, it works fine and give me the response message.

Can anyone help me with this? Thx

Update: my code is very simple

```
import urllib2,json
url = 'https://www.douban.com/service/auth2/token'
res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print json.loads(res.read())
```

Comment: Maybe browser has different proxy settings than python?

Comment: What is the code you used?

Comment: I tried following the URL, this is what came back: "{"msg":"required_parameter_is_missing: client_id","code":113,"request":"GET \/auth2\/token"}"

Perhaps you need to perform the request with a token/identifier? Do you have correct permissions to make that URL request via Python? It seems the server can't recognise your request leading to the problem.